# Symfony2: how to add a Doctrine Entity Array to FormBuilder

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i'm working with Symfony and Doctrine, i have a function that will select rows based on specific criteria:

```
$entities = $repository->getSomeEntities();
```

now i want to render those entities in a choice list, i checked the `entity` FormType but i couldn't achieve what i'm looking for.

Example:

```
     $builder->add('id','entity', array(
        'class' => 'Path\To\Entity',
        'property' => 'id'
    ));
```

the above code works fine except it selects all the Entities.

i checked Symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html and it seems that the only way to achieve this is by using query_builder option *which wont work for my case*

Is there anyway to add the `$entities` array to my form as a choice list ?

Comment: Just reread your question. I'm curious why `query_builder` cannot achieve what you want...

Comment: please comment what exactly youre trying to achieve and why this can't be achieved using the query-builder.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055512/symfony-should-i-use-formbuilder-for-this-form and trying to make that solution reusable for multiple objects. so i choose to pass the entity array to the FormType. so i can easily pass different entities array[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that you implement `ChoiceListProvider`. There are many implementation built into `Symfony` but you might need something as simple as `SimpleChoiceListProvider`.

1. Pass `EntityManager` instance to form (either via constructor or options)
2. Define form field as `choice`, not `entity`
3. Set its `choice_list` to `new MySimpleChoiceLIstProvider($this->entityManager)`

You could (probably will) pass something more than just `EntityManager` to provider as you said "will select rows based on specific criteria". If that criteria origins from form itself you should probably do it via `FormEvents` which will give you access to data object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

With what you wrote, there are no reasons the QueryBuilder doesn't work.

You should have something like that :

```
    $builder
            ->add('fieldname', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Path\to\Entity',
                'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                                        return $er->yourFunction();
                                    },
                'required' => true
                ))
```

with "yourFunction" a function of your repository, for your example "getSomeEntities".

could you show us why it doesn't work ?
Thank you