# Symfony 2: get languages (service) in FormType

Tags: symfony, service, containers

It seems that most easy things are hard to do in Symfony 2;

Like this:

I have a service, which returns cultures:

```
public function getCultures()
{
   $langs = LanguageQuery::create()->orderByPosition()->find();
   $cultures = array();
   foreach ($langs as $lang) {
     $cultures[] = $lang->getCulture();
   }
   return $cultures;
}
```

I want to access this in my FormType:

Now.. There is no way I can get the data here.. (cannot call a service container)..

And I don't want to give $CULTURES as an argument to the FormType, (which means I must overwrite every function in every controller).. (This is not very practical..)... So does anyone have a good solution? Or is Symfony 1.4 just better for this easy things..

```
   $builder
        ->add('commentI18ns', 'propel1_translation_collection', array(
            'languages' => array($CULTURES),
            'label' => '',
            'options' => array(
              'columns' => array(
                'name' => array('label' => 'Name'),
                'description' => array(
                'label' => 'Description', 
                'type' => 'textarea',
                )
              ),
              'data_class' => 'MyDataClass'
            )
          ))
          ->add('is_active')
          ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your form type as a service and intead of doing:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(),...);
```

do this:

```
$form = $this->createForm('my.custom_form_type'); // service id
```

Then it's just matter of defining your service to receive `EntityManager` as an argument. Presto! You have access to `EntityManager` from within your form type.

### Another solution:

I have answered similar albeit a bit more complex `SO` question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086151/symfony2-how-to-add-a-doctrine-entity-array-to-formbuilder/20086277#20086277)**.

Comment: But I don't want to alter things in the controller, because these are from an AdminBundle (which means that I must overwrite every single controller with this $form = $this->createForm('my.custom_form_type');...

Comment: If this is not possible... I cant believe it.. but then it's a no go- with symfony 2..

Comment: $builder
            ->add('commentI18ns', 'propel1_translation_collection', array(
                'languages' => LanguagePeer::getCultures(),
                'label' => '',